# Services are registered with Eureka but not accessable from browser because of DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: spring-cloud

When I register a service with Eureka I can go to Eureka url http://localhost:8761/ and see that it's up:

`RANDOM-ANIMAL  n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - host.docker.internal:random-animal:8082`

Then I open RANDOM-ANIMAL in browser http://random-animal/random and see an error:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

What can be the cause of this problem?

P.S.

It worked some time ago but something changed on PC and I can't fix it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random-animal` is not a known hostname outside of docker, but if you expose port 8082, you can make it available on localhost, so  make sure you map the port 8082 when you start the container (`-p 8082:8082`).

You can additionally map `random-animal` to `127.0.0.1` in your `hosts` file so that you can use that host too if you want.

Comment: I've removed Docker Desktop from autostart and now see RANDOM-ANIMAL n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - DESKTOP-UHTR2G1:random-animal:8082 and get the same error. I didn't run apps in docker at all.

Comment: In this case, just use localhost:8082, random-animal is the service name in Eureka for client side load-balancing. Also, as I said, you can additionally map random-animal to 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file so that you can use that host too if you want.